# samba mount failed with "CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -6" and "is not a valid block device"

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

Environment:

- server: Windows
- client: RHEL 6.7 (samba-common-3.6.23-20.el6.x86_64) or Debian Wheezy (samba-common-bin 2:3.6.6-6+deb7u7)

Client's /etc/fstab:

```
//10.0.0.10/share/ /media/smb    cifs    _netdev,user,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,noperm,username=XXXX,password=XXXX,domain=aa.bb.cc
```

Mounting:

```
$ sudo mount /media/smb/
mount: //10.0.0.10/share/ is not a valid block device
$ dmesg | tail
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -6
```

Answer (score 3):

Possible issue is CIFS/SMB version

```
//192.168.1.1/MyShare/    /mnt/cifs  cifs vers=2.1,username=user1,password=passwd1   0       0
```

Comment: cifs version was the problem for me. Moving from 1.0 to 2.1 (like you said) solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `cifs-utils` to be able to mount CIFS shares:

Red Hat/CentOS related:

```
$ sudo yum install cifs-utils
```

Debian/Ubuntu related:

```
$ sudo apt install cifs-utils
```

Solution found here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/mount-10-52-0-102-jim-dpc-is-not-a-valid-block-device-893664/

Answer (score 1):

Might be related to SMBv1/CIFS removal in Windows 10 / Windows Server v1709 (RS3):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034314/smbv1-is-not-installed-windows-10-and-windows-server-version-1709